# How to find the frequency of characters in a string in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

How can I count the frequency of characters in a string and then output them in sort of a table?

For example, if I input the word "happy" the result would be

```
h 1  
a 1  
p 2  
y 1
```

If this could be ordered in ASCII order too that would be brilliant.

I know I need to use the count function, any other hints would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** All the answers are brilliant, only I'm such a beginner at Haskell that I don't actually understand what they are doing.

Answer (score 46):

The simplest solution is to use a [`Data.Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Map.html) to store the intermediate mapping from character to frequency. You can then construct the counts easily using [`fromListWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:fromListWith). Since `Data.Map` is sorted, you get them in ASCII order for free.

```
λ> :m + Data.Map
λ> let input = "happy"
λ> toList $ fromListWith (+) [(c, 1) | c <- input]
[('a',1),('h',1),('p',2),('y',1)]
```

---

**So what's happening here?**

The idea is to build a `Data.Map` (a tree map) using the characters as keys and the frequencies as values.

First, we take the input string and make tuples of each character with a `1` to indicate one occurrence.

```
λ> [(c, 1) | c <- input]
[('h',1),('a',1),('p',1),('p',1),('y',1)]
```

Next, we use `fromListWith` to build a sorted map from these key-value pairs by repeatedly inserting each key-value pair into a map. We also give it a function which will be used when a key was already in the map. In our case, we use `(+)` so that when a character is seen multiple times, we add the count to the existing sum.

Finally we covert the map back into a list of key-value tuples using `toList`.

Comment: I think im being stupid, but is this a programme? Im such a noob at haskell so sorry if its a stupid question.

Comment: @Hagrid123: The examples are taken from a GHCi (interpreter) session, which is slightly different from what you'd find in a Haskell source file. For example `let` is used for top-level bindings and `:m` can be used to import a module.

Comment: For the record, the hallmark of a GHCi prompt is the `>` character.  When you first launch ghci you will likely see `Prelude>`; note the modules in scope are listed in the prompt.  hammar's ghci prompt seems to be pimped out.

Answer (score 11):

There's probably something shorter, but this works:

```
Prelude> import Data.List
Prelude Data.List> map (\x -> (head x, length x)) $ group $ sort "happy"
[('h',1),('a',1),('p',2),('y',1)]
```

Comment: You'll have to sort the input first to cover cases like `"pappy"` where the occurrences of `p` are not contiguous.

Comment: and note that `(\x -> (head x, length x)) == head &&& length`, where `(&&&)` is from `Control.Arrow`.

Comment: @Conal: I know `Control.Arrow`, but given this rather simplistic approach it seemed like overkill. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Answer (score 5):

`func xs = map (\a -> (head a, length a)) $ group $ sort xs`

Comment: `groupBy (\x y -> x == y)` is the same as `group`

Comment: Yes, I realised that the moment I posted it. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use list comprehension, no need for any imports or sorting.

```
[ (x,c) | x<-['A'..'z'], let c = (length.filter (==x)) "happy", c>0 ]
```

Result:

```
[('a',1),('h',1),('p',2),('y',1)]
```

Above is the filtered and rewritten (only character with count > 0) from:

```
[(x,(length.filter (==x)) "happy" ) | x<-['A'..'z']]
```

Explanation:

- Make a list of all characters that match a given character (A..z).
- For each character, count this list (==length)
- Put this count in a tuple with the character

Comment: I like this! It’s really helpful for when you’re only interested in frequencies for some characters instead of all characters in the input string. Very neat.

Comment: This is pretty, but filter isn't free, and this approach makes an O(n^2) algorithm out of something that can be done in expected O(n), if you have a hashmap available.

Answer (score 0):

I'll scetch a solution step by step. A shorter solution is possible using standard functions.

You want a sorted result, therefore

```
result = sort cs
    where
```

*cs* would be a list of tuples, where the first element is the character and the second element is the number of times it appears.

```
        cs = counts "happy"
        counts [] = []
        counts (c:cs) = (c, length otherc + 1) : counts nonc where
             (otherc, nonc) = partition (c==) cs
```

That's all.

Interestingly, counts works on any list of items that support the == operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Data.Array (Ix, accumArray, assocs)

eltDist :: (Bounded a, Ix a, Eq b, Num b) => [a] -> [(a, b)]
eltDist str = filter ((/=0) . snd ) $ 
     assocs (accumArray (+) 0 (minBound, maxBound) [(i, 1) | i <- str])
```

"minBound" and "maxBound" are going to depend on the range of the type inferred for i. For **Char** it will be 0 - 1,114,111, which is extravagant but not impossible. It would be especially convenient if you were counting Unicode chars. If you are only interested in ASCII strings, then (0, 255) would do. A nice thing about arrays is that they can be indexed by any type that can be mapped to an integer. See **Ix**.

assocs pulls the indices and counts out of the array into a list of pairs and filter disposes of the unused ones.

Answer (score -4):

```
//Count the frequency of character in a string 

package waytocreateobject;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Freqchara {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int c = 0, x = 0, loop = 26, space = 0;
        int count[] = new int[loop];
        //Arrays.fill(count, x);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str =sc.nextLine();
        char[] charr = str.toCharArray();
        int aa = str.length();
        //System.out.println(str.charAt(10));
        //System.out.println(str.charAt(11));
        for (int mm = 0; mm < aa; mm++) {
            if (str.charAt(c) != '\0') {    //Considering characters from 'a' to 'z' only and ignoring others.
                if ((str.charAt(c) >= 'a') && (str.charAt(c) <= 'z')) {
                    x = (int) str.charAt(c) - (int) 'a';
                    // System.out.println(x);
                    count[x] = count[x] + 1;
                }
                c++;
            } else {}
        }

        // printing all the charcter
        int i = 97;
        for (int j = 0; j < loop; j++) {
            char ch = (char) (i + j);
            System.out.println(ch + "  occurs  " + count[j] + " times in the string");
        }
        System.out.println("  occurs " + space);
    }
}
```

Comment: step 1: convert the given string into an array of charcter.
step 2:create an interger array of size 26
step 3: check each character from array and if it is within the range [a-z] only then increment  by 1 of that character in the integer array of size 26 of that particular block.

Comment: step 4: traverse the integer array from 0 to 25 where 0---'a' and 25---'z'