# Haskell compare all list items

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Edit: it's hard to describe what I'm trying to do, but here's a try (from the comments):

I am building a wordfeud solver, so I have a word, and some letters (both char list). I applied this ( [How to find the frequency of characters in a string in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108559/how-to-find-the-frequency-of-characters-in-a-string-in-haskell) ) to both lists to get the frequency of all letters. What I'm doing now is iterating though the 'word' char list, and checking if all chars occur sufficiently in the 'letters' char list.

I have written a Haskell function that compares two lists by applying a function to the items of both lists, and comparing the results.

The comparison is done like this:

```
hasLetters' :: [Char] -> [Char] -> Bool
hasLetters' word letters = (getCharOccurrence (head word) (getCharOccurrences word)) <= (getCharOccurrence (head word) (getCharOccurrences letters))
```

This only compares the occurrences of the first letter of the word. But ALL words should be compared (and the result should be TRUE for all of them).

I don't really know how to accomplish this. I found the 'all' method that lets me define a predicate, that's pretty good. It looks like this:

```
all (<= (getCharOccurrence (head word) (getCharOccurrences letters)))
```

(I think that's correct)
It makes sure that every item that goes into the list is smaller than or equal to the result of the provided function.

BUT: the 'all' method needs another parameter. This would be the 'source' parameter that defines what should be compared to the predicate. This would be easy when this were just a list, then I would do something like this:

```
all (<= (getCharOccurrence (head word) (getCharOccurrences letters))) [0..10]
```

But the problem is: I dont have a list of results like this, I need to compare it to the result of:

```
(getCharOccurrence (head word) (getCharOccurrences letters))
```

I figured that I could apply this function to every character in the 'word' char list with the 'map' function, but I dont know how to use it. I started like this:

```
map (getCharOccurrence (head word) (getCharOccurrences word)) word
```

But that's wrong.

So what I (think I) need: apply the above function to all characters of the 'word' char list, and compare it to the predicate.

But maybe I'm just think the wrong way. I'm an absolute Haskell/functional programming newbie. Please help me out :-)

Comment: Could you give a concise example of what it is you want to solve?  I find it hard to decode from just a function name and use that doesn't even do what you want.

Comment: I'm sorry if it's not clear, it's hard to describe. But I am building a wordfeud solver, so I have a word, and some letters (both char list). I applied this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108559/how-to-find-the-frequency-of-characters-in-a-string-in-haskell) to both lists to get the frequency of all letters. What I'm doing now is iterating though the 'word' char list, and checking if all chars occur sufficiently in the 'letters' char list. Hope that helps.

Comment: I also don't understand what you want, couldn't you just give some simple examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from what I understand you have a string `word` with the word you would like to form and a list of chars `letters` representing the tiles at your disposal. You want to check whether the word may be formed by the tiles or not.

Here I'm assuming the functions you've mentioned have the types

```
getCharOccurrence :: Char -> [(Char, Integer)] -> Integer
getCharOccurrences :: [Char] -> [(Char, Integer)]
```

First, you need to modify `hasLetters'` to take a Char parameter instead of using `head word`:

```
hasLetters' :: Char -> [Char] -> [Char] -> Bool
hasLetters' c word letters = (getCharOccurrence c (getCharOccurrences word)) <= (getCharOccurrence c (getCharOccurrences letters))
```

Then you can combine the above to a master function (let's call it `sufficientTiles`) with

```
sufficientTiles :: [Char] -> [Char] -> Bool
sufficientTiles word letters = and $ map (\c -> hasLetters' c word letters) word
```

What we've done here is to map the `hasLetter'` function to each character of `word`. This will give us a list of Bools. We then use `and` to check that all elements of that list are `True`.

Comment: Yes, you completely understood my question and got the types for getCharOccurrence and getCharOccurrences right :-) A real dumb question now, but how do I use your last expression? Let's assume I want to check if the word "happy" can be formed with the letters "appyhg", how do I do that?

Comment: You probably want to define it as a function, let's call it `sufficientTiles`. So declare it with `sufficientTiles word letters = and $ ...` and then use with `sufficientTiles "happy" "appyhg"`.

Comment: Thanks you very very much! Works like a charm, the puzzle is now solved :)

Comment: You can use `all` in place of `and $ map`, i.e. `all (\c -> ...) word`.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [multiset](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/multiset/0.2.1/doc/html/Data-MultiSet.html) package:

```
import Data.MultiSet
compareAll as bs = fromList as `isSubsetOf` fromList bs
```

or:

```
import Data.Function
import Data.MultiSet
compareAll = isSubsetOf `on` fromList
```

Answer (score 1):

So I think I understand that you want to compare two lists.  The test passes if the second list has at least as many of each element as the first list.  Thus, you need a constraint of at least equality but order would help.

There are many solutions, the one that comes to mind first is sort each list, group and count the unique elements, and ensure all results are `<=`:

```
someCompare a b = let op :: String -> [(Char,Int)]
                      op = map (head &&& length) . group . sort
                  in [c <= k | (x,c) <- op a, k <- maybeToList (lookup x (op b))]
```

Or you can use a map of counters and union the two maps:

```
someCompare2 a b =
        let op = foldl' (\m c -> Map.insertWith (+) c 1 m) Map.empty
        in all (<= 0) . Map.elems $ Map.unionWith (+) (op a) (Map.map negate $ op b)
```

Etc etc.