# Haskell include file and output?

Tags: file, function, haskell, output

my assignment is to make a word solver in Haskell. The idea is that you are given a few random letters. You can type these random letters in Haskell and it returns a list of words that the letter can form. For learning more about this, i've used [Haskell compare all list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278318/haskell-compare-all-list-items) however i'm now stuck at the last part:
I have a function which reads in a file and stores every word in a line:

```
getList :: FilePath -> IO [String]
getList path= do contents<- readFile "wordlist.txt"
                 return(lines contents)
```

Then I also have another function called randomTiles:

```
randomTiles :: [Char] -> [Char] -> Bool
randomTiles word letters = all (\c  -> LettersinWord' c word letters) word
```

This function basically looks at the input of random letters you have given and shows the user if a word can be formed with them,  if yes it returns true else false.

Now I have to make a function which loads the getList into the randomTiles so that the given random letters can be compared with the words of the list. If randomTiles returns true, it has to print the word that can be formed. However I really have no idea how to go about this since i'm new to Haskell and i'm not even sure its possible.
I have tried it in this way but i'm sure its not the way to do it:

```
solver:: [Char]->[String]
solver a = test1
    where 
    randomTiles a b = getList a 
    test1= if randomTiles = true then print
```

To make sure, the code is supposed to work like this; my given letters are "lohel"
output:  hello
         hell
         hole

Answer (score 1):

I would start by making a function that tests the randomTiles against all the words in a given dictionary:

```
allMatches :: [Char] -> [String] -> [String]
allMatches randomLetters words =
    filter (\word -> randomTiles word randomLetters) words
```

I think of the 'solver' as loading the word dictionary and returning a new function that will print all the words that can be formed from a set of random letters.  There are a couple variations of this, which mostly involve where the IO happens and whether or not the word list is loaded into memory once or on each access.

```
solver :: FilePath -> [Char] -> IO [String]
solver path randomLetters = do
    allWords <- getList path
    return $ allMatches randomLetters allWords
```

The solver returns a list of matches; it's simple to print them by using 'mapM_ putStrLn'.  Since this function is printing the strings, not returning them, it's an IO action that returns `()`:

```
defaultSolver :: [Char] -> IO ()
defaultSolver randomLetters =
    matches <- solver "/usr/share/dict/words" randomLetters
    mapM_ putStrLn matches
```

There's still a problem with your `randomTiles` function unfortunately.  Is `LettersinWord'` is supposed to start with a lowercase letter?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Yes, lettersinWord'is supposed to be lowercase, because its a function in my code. You can look at (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278318/haskell-compare-all-list-items) because my code/functions looks a lot like this one. I think your idea of function solver is right, however I have the function that reads the file and the solver function as seperate functions in my code atm. I was looking for a way to use randomTiles in my solverfunction with the wordlistfile als parameter in randomTiles so that when randomTiles returns true > print the word?Is this possible?

Comment: @xylia I'm not really sure what you're asking for.  That's exactly what this code does: when randomTiles is True the word gets printed.  You could rearrange things and call `putStrLn` inside `solver`, sure, but it really doesn't matter AFAICT.

Answer (score 1):

```
solver:: [Char] -> FilePath -> IO [String]
solver letters file = do
    words <- getList file
    return $ filter (flip randomTiles letters) words
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have tried out your code, however it gave me a ambiguous error. So I imported qualified Data.Map as Map and included that in the code `return $ Map.filter (flip randomTiles letters) words` However it gives me the following error now:     Couldn't match expected type `Map k0 [Char]'
                with actual type `[String]'

Comment: This filter is from `Data.List`

Comment: hi, thanks for clarifying that, the error is gone now. Sorry for bothering you again, but do  I have to use print on the solver function as the code returns :     No instance for (Show (FilePath -> IO [String]))
      arising from a use of `print'

Comment: you can use solver like: `solver "hello" "wordsfile.txt" >>= putStr . show`