# Counting occurrences of a character in a string (Haskell)

Tags: string, haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the frequency of characters in a string in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108559/how-to-find-the-frequency-of-characters-in-a-string-in-haskell)

Given an input String, I wish to count the occurrences of each character. I have two approaches (in imperical pseudocode):

```
For each character in the "alphabet"
  traverse the string and increment a counter when the character is found
```

I believe I can implement this in Haskell fairly easily. My second idea is a little trickier:

```
For each character in the string
  increment a counter and store it in a map (or similar data structure)
```

I have little experience with data structures in Haskell, so this second solution is a little more intimidating than the first. However, I certainly would like to learn more either by implementing my own data structure or using something from the built-in libraries.

Does anyone have any suggestions as how I should proceed?

Comment: There's an amusing one-liner for this that solves the problem in a completely different way: sort first, then count consecutive runs of the same character. (the one-liner in question involves sort and group - I'll leave the rest up to you)

Comment: @Carl Interesting approach! And since data is immutable, the original string is still intact.

Comment: `group` and `map` and `length` come in handy for Carl's approach as well.

Answer (score 4):

`Data.Map` is the standard for associative arrays. It's in the `containers` package and is pretty well documented, I think. The `insertWith` function may be of particular interest for this problem - it lets you insert a new key and value but also provide a function (you would want to use `+`) to combine the value with the value already in the map, if any.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7108655/946226 for an elegant way of using `Data.Map`.

Answer (score 2):

I assume there probably is a function in Haskell prelude for this (look for `(Eq a, Integral i) => [a] -> a -> i`) but this can be expressed fairly easy as a fold

```
count a = foldr (\x sum -> if x == a then sum+1 else sum) 0
```

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:foldr

As for maps, look up the Data.Map module. (Also it's fairly easy to write a simple list based map)

Comment: Too much detail. I am asking for "suggestions" not "fully implemented solutions."

Comment: That was a suggestion though. If the goal was to count the character frequencies in a string you would probably go with your second idea, which is why I suggested the Data.Map module.

Answer (score 2):

In Haskell, the `=` sign is used just like in mathematics, to define *equations*. Idiomatic Haskell eschews mutation (e.g. "increment a counter") and instead encourages solutions that make use of pure functions. However, using `ST` you can write algorithms using mutation just like you would in any other language.

Consider the task of determining how many times a single character appears in a string.
According to your English description

> traverse the string and increment a counter when the character is found

the Python implementation would be

```
def count(c, s):
  i = 0
  for c0 in s:
    if c == c0:
      i += 1
  return i
```

Using ST we can write the exact same code, although it is slightly more verbose, because all creating, reading, and writing of mutable variables is explicitly named:

```
import Control.Monad (when, forM_)
import Control.Monad.ST (runST)
import Data.STRef

count :: Char -> String -> Int
count c s = runST $ do     -- def count(c, s):
  i <- newSTRef 0          --   i = 0
  forM_ s $ \c' -> do      --   for c0 in s:
    when (c == c') $ do    --     if c == c0:
      modifySTRef i (+1)   --       i += 1
  readSTRef i              --   return i
```

As I said before, this is not idiomatic Haskell, but nevertheless I see no reason to eschew ST when you already have an imperative algorithm in mind that uses mutation. Since the mutation is localized to the function, and is unobservable from outside, we can use `runST` to hide the implementation details and present a pure interface `Char -> String -> Int`.

Comment: For some reason I found this solution not non-Haskell.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend:

- reading up on [folds](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Fold).  Folds are a very common pattern in functional programming for processing lists.
- looking through some of the [Haskell libraries](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html) (warning: they're extensive and take a while to grok -- but definitely worth the effort).  Solutions to problems such as yours can often be found by glueing together a few pre-defined functions (for example, sort/group/map/length).  This exercise gets you more familiar with the libraries, Haskell syntax and coding style, FP, and solving problems through composition.

Comment: I'm familiar enough with folds to know they exist, but I haven't used them very much yet. Thanks for pointing them out!