# I'm trying to make a frequency table in haskell

Tags: haskell, frequency

```
type FreqTable = [(Char, Int)]

fTable :: String -> FreqTable 
fTable s = [sort $ s, i+1]
    where i = 0
```

As you can see I am trying to return a tuple, but I can't understand why what I have returned isn't acceptable. Obviously this isn't a completed program that returns a frequency table yet but I am just trying to understand how to return this type FreqTable at the moment.

Also any hints to how I would go about creating the frequency table would be much appreciated as I am quite new to Haskell, I don't want the answer just some stepping stones.

Comment: If you want to return a pair, *make a pair*! You've made the list part using `[` and `]`, now make a pair by writing `[(sort s, i+1)]`.

Comment: I just tried that and when I try to load it I "parse error (possibly  incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)" back?

Comment: Try answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108559/how-to-find-the-frequency-of-characters-in-a-string-in-haskell), or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517114/count-frequency-of-each-element-in-a-list). Try [google](https://www.google.ru/search?q=haskell+frequency+count&oq=haskell+freque&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.7226j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical element of `[(Char,Int)]` would look like

```
[('a',3),('b',4)]
```

writing

```
[sort $ s, i+1]
```

puts a string and an integer in the same list, which is an error since lists must be homogeneous (composed of things having the same type).

By then way, `sort $ s` is the same as `sort s`, so I'll use the latter from now on.

Note that the above is not even a list of pairs. Let's try adding a pair:

```
[(sort s, i+1)]
```

this is a correct list, but has type `[(String,Int)]`, not `[(Char,Int)]`, hence it still won't do.

You need to tear the (sorted) string apart to individual `Char`s. This can be done e.g. with a list comprehension

```
[(c,1) | c <- sort s ]
```

this is not what you want, but at least has the right type. Now you have to add all these `1`s for the same `c`...

If you want to leverage some library functions, lookup function `group` in the standard library.